# Swift force casting to string

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have some data coming. from an api , any way i created a model to transform json to `Object`.

the problem is that there is a `key` in json causing my problem.

this key may return an `boolean` or an `string` so i need to force cast it to string "i don't have access to the api"
my code :

```
enum ISpecial: Codable {
case bool(Bool)
case string(String)

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
        self = .bool(x)
        return
    }
    if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
        self = .string(x)
        return
    }
    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ISpecial.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ISpecial"))
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
    case .bool(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    case .string(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    }
}}
```

then in the view :

```
VStack(alignment:.leading){
            Text(product.name ?? "No name")
                .padding(.vertical,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.9))
            VStack{
                Text(product.price ?? " ").strikethrough()
                Text( product.special ?? " ")
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post code as text. Also, what do you want the `Text` to display when `special` is the `bool` case?

Comment: ok i pasted the code, in case of bool a don't want to show any thing @Sweeper

Comment: Can you also show the declaration of `product` and the declaration of its type?

Comment: sure i will give a link to the tool that i use to parse json to swift [link](https://app.quicktype.io?share=TOIiLeNHekLOpFOXBIP0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to `ISpecial` that returns a `String` if it is the `string` case, and `nil` otherwise:

```
var stringValue: String? {
    if case .string(let s) = self {
        return s
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Text( product.special?.stringValue ?? " ")
```

Comment: Great it works !, can i make it done with out modifying ISpecial ? @Sweeper